# Take a mutable slice from a vector with a different length?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a vector as a buffer [like this](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/buffer.rs#L53-L66), I'm wondering if there is a way to take a slice from the vector without [growing it](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/buffer.rs#L23-L25), so that code like this work:

```
fn example(r: Read) {
    let buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1024);
    let slice: &mut[u8] = &mut buffer;
    r.read(slice); // doesnt work since the slice has length zero
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one was to just take a slice of the capacity, you would have a slice of uninitialized data. This is unsafe.

You *can* do this with `Vec`'s `set_len`. However

- This is unsafe. Reading the data is memory safe, but a vector of another type, or misuse of `set_len`, may not be. Overflow checking and proper cleanup is important.
- This could well be a significant security flaw.
- If you are using non-primitive types, you need to consider panic safety.
- [The standard library has a policy against allowing reads to uninitialized memory, even if memory-safe.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23668)

The basic way of doing this is

```
unsafe {
    buffer.set_len(buffer.capacity());
    let new_len = try!(r.read(slice));
    buffer.set_len(cmp::min(buffer.len(), new_len));
}
```

The `cmp::min` is needed if you don't totally trust `read`'s implementation, since incorrect output can result in too-large set length.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Since growing the vec also uses unsafe code, what approach do you recomend?

Comment: I recommend `Vec.resize(capacity, 0)`, since it's safe and easy. Only move to the unsafe variants if you really need the absolute maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add three details to @Veedrac answer.

1 - This is the relevant code that creates the slices from `Vec<T>`, and in both cases the slice goes from the start of the vector up to `self.len`:

[fn deref(&self) -> &[T]](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/377c11aa83c1d2f6cc07fe178eb18a31e1813304/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1131-L1142)

[fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [T]](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/377c11aa83c1d2f6cc07fe178eb18a31e1813304/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1144-L1153)

2 - There is an [optimization in the TcpStream](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/98f287240ff9518c1ea5519c5cd03dc2ba6d4452/src/libstd/sys/common/io.rs#L16-L52) to avoid zeroing the memory, much like @Veedrac's alternative, but it is only used for `read_to_end` and not in `read`. And the `BufReader` that does zeroing starts with small allocations for [performance reasons](http://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23815)

3 - The slice has no information about the vector size, so the vector the length must be updated anyways, otherwise the buffer will be larger than the data and the zeros will be used.